# How to purge a document

Tags: pouchdb

How can I purge (not remove) a PouchDB document similar to CouchDB [_purge operation](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Purge_Documents).

Note: Purge is different from remove (or delete). It is as though the database had never heard of document at all.

Comment: I don't think pouchdb supports the purge operation at the moment. You might consider opening an issue for it on github.

Comment: The issue [already exists](https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/issues/802).