# pouchdb remove by startkey and endkey

Tags: pouchdb

Is there a way to delete records using startkey and endkey in pouchdb with angular? My current pouchdb for geo locations looks like this, which is fine. The closest question I came across is this one [PouchDb - remove object inside document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25078521/pouchdb-remove-object-inside-document) but it didn't work out for me.

I am hoping to avoid getting the whole document and just query-delete (I admit I am looking at it from a sql pov only DELETE WHERE kind of thing). Any input is welcome:

```
state_123
county_1_123
state_124
```

Basically, I want to delete all states.

```
   db.allDocs(
  {
    startkey: "state_",
    endkey: "state_" + "\uffff",
    include_docs: true
  },
  function(err, response) {
    // handle err or response
    if (!err) {
      console.log("pouchdb states returned ", response);

      // i was thinking of finding a way to delete those
      // responses in an efficient way

      let deleteStates = [];
      response.rows.forEach(item => {
        let doc = item["doc"];
        doc['_deleted'] = true;
        deleteStates.push(doc);
        });

        vm.pouch.bulkDocs(deleteStates);

    } else {
      console.log("error getting states", err);
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: Not in a single operation, no. You can query all docs with startkey and endkey, then delete all of the results in bulk.

Comment: Thanks @Flimzy. Can you check my attempt now. It added _delete = true to all the states i want to delete correctly but I was hoping they get completely deleted from the database.

Comment: To completely delete something from the database, you must use purge. This is not currently possible in PouchDB. See [related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17028018/13860) and [issue](https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/issues/802).